# How do i use an Expression<Func<T>> in a linq statement if my navigation property is a single item?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an expression that maps the database object from another system to a standard object that I can use across any system.

Ex:

```
private static Expression<Func<excessive_location, MyLocation>> LocationMap =
    l => new MyLocation()
        {
            Id = l.unique_id,
            Code = l.location_code,
            Active = l.active

            ...Other properties
        }
```

This works exactly as I expect in the following situation

```
public IEnumerable<MyLocation> GetActiveLocations()
        {
            return otherSystem.location_table
                .Select(LocationMap)
                .Where(l => l.Active == true)
                .ToList();
        }
```

But I cant seem to figue out a way to make it work as part of another expression

```
private static Expression<Func<excessive_user, User>> UserMap =
    e => new User()
        {
            Id = e.unique_id,
            FirstName = e.fname,
            LastName = e.lname,
            Location = e.excessive_location
                .Select(LocationMap)  // will not work since
                                      // e.excessive_location is not a collection
        };
```

I know I can compile it to a function but then it will have to execute for every user out of thousands.  What is the proper way to make this work?

Comment: Are you concerned about the _performance_ impact of compiling it each time or are you trying to keep them as expressions so that they can be translated to SQL (solving the SELECT N+1 problem)?

Comment: I wanted it to all be compiled into a SQL statement under the hood specifically to address the performance impact of running a function on each iteration.  I hope I'm understanding your question correctly and the whole idea of using an Expressions in general.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve the goal, you'll need some expression helpers.

Let me first show you the resulting code:

```
private static Expression<Func<excessive_location, MyLocation>> LocationMap =
    l => new MyLocation()
    {
        Id = l.unique_id,
        Code = l.location_code,
        Active = l.active
    };

private static Expression<Func<excessive_user, User>> UserMap =
    Utils.Expr((excessive_user u) => new User
    {
        Id = u.unique_id,
        FirstName = u.fname,
        LastName = u.lname
    })
    .BindMemberInit(u => u.Location, 
        Utils.Expr((excessive_user u) => u.excessive_location).Bind(LocationMap));
```

Now the helpers.

The first one called `Expr` is a simple method that allows you to define expression without local variable.

The second one called `Bind` allows you to bind expression to another expression accessor.

So having

`(excessive_user u) => u.excessive_location`

and

`(excessive_location l) => new MyLocation { Id = l.unique_id, .... }`

you can make

`(excessive_user u) => new MyLocation { Id = u.excessive_location.inique_id, ...}`

The third one called `BindMemberInit` allows you to add new member initialization to the existing `new { ... }` expression.

The last one called `ReplaceParameter` allows you to replace expression parameter with another expression.

Here is the full code:

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, TResult>> Expr<T, TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> e) { return e; }

    public static Expression<Func<TOuter, TResult>> Bind<TOuter, TInner, TResult>(this Expression<Func<TOuter, TInner>> source, Expression<Func<TInner, TResult>> resultSelector)
    {
        var body = resultSelector.Body.ReplaceParameter(resultSelector.Parameters[0], source.Body);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TOuter, TResult>>(body, source.Parameters);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<TSource, TTarget>> BindMemberInit<TSource, TTarget, TMember, TValue>(this Expression<Func<TSource, TTarget>> expression, Expression<Func<TTarget, TMember>> member, Expression<Func<TSource, TValue>> value)
    {
        var binding = Expression.Bind(
            ((MemberExpression)member.Body).Member,
            value.Body.ReplaceParameter(value.Parameters[0], expression.Parameters[0]));
        var body = (MemberInitExpression)expression.Body;
        return expression.Update(body.Update(body.NewExpression, body.Bindings.Concat(new[] { binding })), expression.Parameters);
    }

    static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression, ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
    {
        return new ParameterReplacer { Source = source, Target = target }.Visit(expression);
    }

    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression Source;
        public Expression Target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            return node == Source ? Target : base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So what we need here is a two methods.  One to compose one expression with another, that is to take an expression that computes a value, another expression that takes that output and computes a new value, and creates a new expression that takes the input of the first and produces the output of the second, using both expressions.

We'll start by creating an expression to get the location from a user:

```
Expression<Func<excessive_user, excessive_location>> locationProjection = 
    user => user.excessive_location;
```

Then we'll compose that with your expression to turn the location into a `MyLocation`:

```
Expression<Func<excessive_user, MyLocation>> mappedLocationProject = 
    locationProjection.Compose(LoactionMap);
```

Next we'll need a very similar, but slightly different method that can combine two expressions together, being able to take an expression, and another that takes the same input, and the output of the original, and produces a new output.

This method would allow us to write the following:

```
mappedLocationProject.Combine((user, location) => new User()
        {
            Id = user.unique_id,
            FirstName = user.fname,
            LastName = user.lname,
            Location = location
        };
```

Here's the method to compose expressions:

```
public static Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>
    Compose<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate>> first,
    Expression<Func<TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFirstParam), "param");

    var newFirst = first.Body.Replace(first.Parameters[0], param);
    var newSecond = second.Body.Replace(second.Parameters[0], newFirst);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>(newSecond, param);
}
```

And here's the implementation of `Combine`:

```
public static Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>
    Combine<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate>> first,
    Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFirstParam), "param");

    var newFirst = first.Body.Replace(first.Parameters[0], param);
    var newSecond = second.Body.Replace(second.Parameters[0], param)
        .Replace(second.Parameters[1], newFirst);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>(newSecond, param);
}
```

They both use the following method to replace all instances of one expression with another:

```
internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
    Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}
```

Comment: I'm not very experienced with expression trees and visitors so I have no idea what this is doing exactly but I plugged it all in anyway.  Good news is it gives the the output i expect but the bad new is it is significantly slower than me using the LocationMap for the AllLocations method and just rewriting the same map inside of the EmployeeMap expression.  By a factor of 10 i would say.  Any idea on how I could speed this up to be comparable?  Perhaps a way to save the Combined/Composed expressions to reuse?

Comment: @user3893011 Just save the expression in a variable, just as you would any other computed value that you want to store.  Expressions are no different than anything else in that regard.